# When I set the value for useRef, it is an empty string and don't understand why

Tags: reactjs

I have this custom hook for fetching data and was really confused why it wasn't working. I found out that when I am useRef-ing my query, it comes out as an empty string. Weird thing is that I use it again for the orderBy and it comes out fine. What am I missing here?

```
export const useCollection = (collection, _query, _orderBy) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // if we don't use a ref --> infinite loop in useEffect
  // _query is an array and is "different" on every function call
  const query = useRef(_query).current;
  const orderBy = useRef(_orderBy).current;

  if (collection === "items") {
    console.log("query:", query);
    // output: query:
    console.log(query === "");
    // output: true
    console.log("_query:", _query);
    // output: _query: (3) [t, '==', 'LoRPkXCySrXqndbrdoUk']
    console.log("orderBy:", orderBy);
    // output: orderBy: (2) ['pickedUpAt', 'desc']
    console.log("_orderBy:", _orderBy);
    // output: _orderBy: (2) ['pickedUpAt', 'desc']
  }
```

Comment: This would be the logs you would get if useCollection was called with empty _query and collection !== "items" on the first call, then updated to "items", and set the _query. What is the usage of useCollection?

Comment: ahh ok. I think I didnt understand useRef. So I am doing exactly that and the first time useCollection gets called, it is with an empty string as the query so I guess it never actually get reinitialized after that when I do call it with query as the array?

Comment: Yes. `query` will ONLY get updated when you assign a new value to it like `ref.current = 42`

Comment: There shouldn't be an infinite loop in your useEffect, but I can't help because you haven't shown it.